# Use a python file from a separate maven module

Tags: python, maven

I have a Maven project with multiple modules. Many of the modules contain the code and config for a separate application. I have a python script with each application that will take care of launching the application. I also have a separate "helper" python file that has functionality intended to be used by each of the application launcher scripts.

I'd like to avoid having to have a copy of the helper in each application module, so I was hoping I could figure out a way to either make the python file a "dependency", or to copy it into the built distribution (zip file containing the needed jar files and other configuration) during the maven build process.

I already have a "common" module that contains Java classes commonly used by code in many of the other modules, so this module is already a dependency required by other module pom files. Seems like the perfect place to put the helper python file. The thing is: maven seems to very good at handling maven artifact dependencies, but I'm not sure how (*or if*) it can handle this type of situation.

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but what is needed to start a Java application except `java -jar application.jar` ?

Comment: Indeed. However, the script takes care of collecting the necessary arguments from the user and constructing the java command line. Each application launcher script uses the "helper" script to build the command line.

Comment: Can be done in java as well or even generate a script via [appassembler-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) cause not everyone has python installed  in particular for a Java application...do you have so many arguments to start your application? Or have correct CLI interface with things like `help` option etc. ?